# An ideal of $\mathcal O_K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $K$ be a number field and let $\mathcal O_K$ be its ring of integers. Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal in $\mathcal O_K$.

> If $I$ is free as a $\mathcal O_K$-module then is it a principal ideal?

I know that any (fractional) $\mathcal O_K$-ideal is generated by at most two elements since $\mathcal O_K$ is Dedekind but is there an easy way to show the above?

Many thanks.

Comment: Assume you have two linearly independent element, and try to find a contradiction using the fact that the ring is commutative (it's actually true for any commutative ring).

Comment: If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are linearly independent then we have a direct sum $\mathcal O_K x_1\oplus \mathcal O_K x_2 \subset I$. Then since $\mathcal O_K$ is a commutative ring, $x_1x_2=x_2x_1\in \mathcal O_K x_1 \cap \mathcal O_K x_2=\{0\}$. Therefore $x_1 x_2=0$ and so either $x_1=0$ or $x_2=0$ since the ring of integers is a domain?

Comment: That seems fine since you're in an integral ring. In a general ring the argument has to be modified a little, but here that's ok.

Comment: How would the argument change for a general ring? I don't think I've used the integrality property anywhere above. Regards

Comment: An integral ring is another name for a domain. For a general ring you have to use the fact that $x_1$ and $x_2$ being linearly independent is stronger than $\mathcal{O}_Kx_1\cap \mathcal{O}x_2 = \{0\}$, it means that if $ax_1+bx_2=0$ then $a=b=0$. Then you can apply that to $a=x_2$ and $b=-x_1$.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I thought you were referring to the fact that $\mathcal O_K$ is the ring of elements of $K$ integral over $\mathbb Z$. regards